# JPA2/Hibernate - Creating a schema on the fly (ie without pre-create the schema manually)?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I use JPA 2 with Hibernate Entity Manager 3.6.4. Once I have marked my entities with various annotations (`@Entity`, `@MappedSuperClass` etc), I put in my persistence.xml file the default schema to use (`hibernate.default_schema` property).

I know it's possible to create automatically the objects contained in the schema.
But is it possible to create the schema itself automatically and then create the objects it contains ?

**EDIT :**
I use this parameter too : `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`, to tell Hibernate to create the schema if it doesn't exists yet. No luck, Hibernate doesn't create it !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have googled a little bit and find this post : [Hibernate hbm2ddl won't create schema before creating tables](http://blog.solidcraft.eu/2011/01/hibernate-hbm2ddl-wont-create-schema.html).

The fact that Hibernate does not create a schema before creating table is a [bug](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-5665). Other database suffer from this situation : H2, Postgresql etc.

[This bug](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-5665) is planned to be fixed with 5.0.0 release of Hibernate.

So, for now, the only workaround is to create the schema by yourself, either manually or by a mean offered by your database vendor, since Hibernate can't do it itself :\

Answer (score 2):

I managed to build a workaround that uses the hbm2ddl default flow.

Since it always calls the "database-object" drop statements BEFORE creating schema, you can do something like this:

```
<database-object>
    <create></create>
    <drop>DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS myschema cascade; CREATE SCHEMA myschema</drop>
</database-object>
```

unfortunately the create clause is mandatory and sadly it's only executed AFTER schema creation, no matter what order you put it on cfg.xml, so I made it empty, that way you don't have errors trying to creating schema again (it was already created together with drop)